# Facebook get_started button doesn't disappear once clicked

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've set up the get_started button for my Facebook page (testing purposes, still not published and won't be).

The POST API call to the `/me/messenger_profile` endpoint returns `success` and the Get Started button correctly appears in the chat with the page.

When clicked, the button correctly triggers a postback call to my BOT Framework app and starts a new conversation, but the Get Started button still remains and blocks the conversation typing input until I refresh the page.

[image]

Is there anyone that encountered the same issue?
It's getting me really nervous.

Thank you.